# Change connection of pivotcache to existing connection

Tags: excel, vba, connection

I am trying to change the connection of a pivotcache object in Excel 2010 VBA to a connection that I have already set up in my workbook.

I can change the connection of a pivot table by

```
ws.PivotTables(i).ChangeConnection ThisWorkbook.Connections( _
            "My Connection Name")
```

However, the pivotcache object doesn't seem to have a ChangeConnection method.

When I try

```
Set ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches(PivotCacheIndex).Connection = ThisWorkbook.Connections("My Connection Name")
```

it says "Object required". It looks as if `ThisWorkbook.Connections("My Connection Name")` is only a string.

The connections I am using are to an MS Access 2010 database and are OLEDB. I have set them up in VBA with no problems.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two choices:

1) Change the PivotCache's `SourceConnectionFile` to point at a different `odc` file.

2) Do a search and replace in its `Connection` property to change the file path, and the same thing with its `CommandText` property to change the tables you're querying.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions, Doug. Sorry I didn't reply before but this is my first post and I thought I would be notified by email of any answers. I will try out your suggestions in a few days and let you know.

Comment: Am still having lots of trouble. Have decided to abandon this for the time being but thanks Doug for your ideas.